# Scripting in logstash

Tags: python, elasticsearch, groovy, logstash

Is it possible to do python like scripting in logstash? I can import the csv data into elasticsearch using logstash. But I need to use update API instead of simply indexing all rows.

Here is my sample csv file...

```
vi /tmp/head.txt
"Home","Home-66497273a5a83c99","Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/1VSZj","919359000000","HMSHOP","916265100000","2016-05-18 08:41:49"
"Home","Home-26497273a5a83c99","Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/1V1","919359000001","HMSHOP","916265100000","2016-05-18 18:41:49"
"Home","Home-36497273a5a83c99","Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/SZj1","919359000001","HMSHOP","916265100000","2016-05-18 12:41:49"
"Home","Home-46497273a5a83c99","Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/1","919359000000","HMSHOP","916265100000","2016-05-18 14:41:49"
"Home","Home-56497273a5a83c99","Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/1VSZj1xc","919359000000","HMSHOP","916265100000","2016-05-18 16:41:49"
```

Here is logstash config file...

```
vi logstash.conf
input {
    file {
        path => "/tmp/head.txt"
        type => "csv"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["user", "messageid", "message", "destination", "code", "mobile", "mytimestamp"]
        separator => ","
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["172.17.0.1"]
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        workers => 1
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that the above configuration is working as expected and all 5 records are stored as 5 separate documents.

here is my docker command...

```
docker run -d -v "/tmp/logstash.conf":/usr/local/logstash/config/logstash.conf -v /tmp/:/tmp/ logstash -f /usr/local/logstash/config/logstash.conf
```

---

The problem is that I need to merge the documents based on destination number. The destination should be the ID of the document. There are some rows with the same destination. For e.g. _id: 919359000001 This document should have both the following records as nested objects.

```
"user": "Home", "messageid": "Home-26497273a5a83c99", "message": "Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/1V1", "code": "HMSHOP", "mobile": "916265100000", "mytimestamp" : "2016-05-18 18:41:49"
"user": "Home", "messageid" "Home-36497273a5a83c99", "message": "Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/SZj1", "code": "HMSHOP", "mobile": "916265100000", "mytimestamp": "2016-05-18 12:41:49"
```

Elasticsearch is correctly converting the csv data to json as shown above. What I need is to reformat the statement to take advantage of scripting using update API
The following code is working correctly.

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{ "update" : { "_id" : "919359000001"} }
{ "script" : { "inline": "ctx._source.parent += ['user': user, 'messageid': messageid, 'message': message, 'code': code, 'mobile': mobile, 'mytimestamp': mytimestamp]", "lang" : "groovy", "params" : {"user": "Home", "messageid": "Home-26497273a5a83c99", "message": "Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/1V1", "code": "HMSHOP", "mobile": "916265100000", "mytimestamp" : "2016-05-18 18:41:49"}}, "upsert": {"parent" : [{"user": "Home", "messageid": "Home-26497273a5a83c99", "message": "Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/1V1", "code": "HMSHOP", "mobile": "916265100000", "mytimestamp" : "2016-05-18 18:41:49"}] }}
{ "update" : { "_id" : "919359000001"} }
{ "script" : { "inline": "ctx._source.parent += ['user': user, 'messageid': messageid, 'message': message, 'code': code, 'mobile': mobile, 'mytimestamp': mytimestamp]", "lang" : "groovy", "params" : {"user": "Home", "messageid": "Home-36497273a5a83c99", "message": "Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/1V13343", "code": "HMSHOP", "mobile": "916265100000", "mytimestamp" : "2016-05-18 12:41:49"}}, "upsert": {"parent" : [{"user": "Home", "messageid": "Home-36497273a5a83c99", "message": "Spice Xlife 350, 3.5inch Android, bit.ly/1V13343", "code": "HMSHOP", "mobile": "916265100000", "mytimestamp" : "2016-05-18 12:41:49"}] }}
```

How do I code in logstash to convert my csv data to look like the above?

---

**Update**

I have python code that works as expected. I will like to know how to modify this code to suit the "output" parameters suggested as per the answer.
In the following example, df_json is a python object that is nothing but python dataframe flattened to json.

```
import copy
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for doc1 in df_json:
        import json
        doc = mydict(doc1)
        docnew = copy.deepcopy(doc)
        del docnew['destination']
        action = '{ "update": {"_id": %s }}\n' % doc['destination'] 
        f.write(action)
        entry = '{ "script" : { "inline": "ctx._source.parent += [\'user\': user, \'messageid\': messageid, \'message\': message, \'code\': code, \'mobile\': mobile, \'mytimestamp\': mytimestamp]", "lang" : "groovy", "params" : %s}, "upsert": {"parent" : [%s ] }}\n' %   (doc, docnew)
        f.write(entry)

! curl -s -XPOST XXX.xx.xx.x:9200/test_index222/doc/_bulk --data-binary @myfile.txt; echo
```

---

**Update 2**

I tried the following configuration and it is replacing (not updating as per script) documents.

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["172.17.0.1"]
        document_id => "%{destination}"
        index => "logstash3-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        workers => 1
        script => "ctx._source.parent += ['user': user, 'messageid': messageid, 'message': message, 'code': code, 'mobile': mobile, 'mytimestamp': mytimestamp]"
        script_type => "inline"
        script_lang =>  "groovy"
        scripted_upsert => "true"
    }
}
```

When I changed the action to "update", I get the following error...

```
:response=>{"update"=>{"_index"=>"logstash4-2016.07.29", "_type"=>"csv", "_id"=>"919359000000", 
"status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"failed to execute script", 
"caused_by"=>{"type"=>"script_exception", "reason"=>"failed to run in line script 
[ctx._source.parent += ['user': user, 'messageid': messageid, 'message': message, 'code': code, 'mobile': mobile, 'mytimestamp': mytimestamp]] 
using lang [groovy]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"missing_property_exception", "reason"=>"No such property: user for class: fe1b423dc4966b0f0b511b732474637705bf3bb1"}}}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

---

**Update 3**

As per Val's answer I added event and I get this error...

```
:response=>{"update"=>{"_index"=>"logstash4-2016.08.06", "_type"=>"csv", "_id"=>"%{destination}", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"failed to execute script", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"script_exception", "reason"=>"failed to run inline script [ctx._source.parent += ['user': event.user, 'messageid': event.messageid, 'message': event.message, 'code': event.code, 'mobile': event.mobile, 'mytimestamp': event.mytimestamp]] using lang [groovy]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"null_pointer_exception", "reason"=>"Cannot execute null+{user=null, messageid=null, message=, code=null, mobile=null, mytimestamp=null}"}}}}}
```

**Update 4**

As per Val's updated answer I tried this...

```
script => "ctx._source.parent = (ctx._source.parent ?: []) + ['user': event.user, 'messageid': event.messageid, 'message': event.message, 'code': event.code, 'mobile': event.mobile, 'mytimestamp': event.mytimestamp]"
```

And got this error:

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-08-12T09:40:48.869000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline main started"}
{:timestamp=>"2016-08-12T09:40:49.517000+0000", :message=>"Error parsing csv", :field=>"message", :source=>"", :exception=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `each_index' for nil:NilClass>, :level=>:warn}
```

Only 2 records were added to the database.

Comment: Change action => "update" not "index".

Answer (score 1):

`elasticsearch` output plugin supports script parameters:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "update"
        hosts => ["172.17.0.1"]
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        workers => 1
        script => "<your script here>"
        script_type => "inline"
        # Set the language of the used script
        # script_lang => 
        # if enabled, script is in charge of creating non-existent document (scripted update)
        # scripted_upsert => (default is false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing action to update did not help. See the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The event is passed to the script in your output using the `event` variable name (by default, but you can change it using the `script_var_name` setting).

So the script in your output needs to account for it.

```
    script => "ctx._source.parent = (ctx._source.parent ?: []) + ['user': event.user, 'messageid': event.messageid, 'message': event.message, 'code': event.code, 'mobile': event.mobile, 'mytimestamp': event.mytimestamp]"
```

Comment: Using this script, I could add only 2 records. It did not update the records the way python does. (question updated)

Comment: It is replacing the current id instead of updating it.

Comment: The error says `Error parsing csv` which has nothing to do with the script in my opinion. It happens before the event reaches the `elasticsearch` output. Can you provide more info, please?

Comment: @shantanuo can you shed some more light on your latest comment? As I said, the error is happening before the script gets a chance to execute.

Comment: Yes. You are right. That error is actually complaining about the blank line in the csv file. The records are correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have working python script, maybe that will be useful ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/lang-python.html

Regarding update nr 2 - I think the error can be fixed by first checking if a document has given field(In this case it's user).